# NodeRed how to return an array of msg object

Tags: node-red

In NodeRed I have this function:

```
var payload = msg.payload;
  if(payload && payload.length > 10) {
    var data = payload.match(/\d+/ig);
    var string = "vcc:"+data[1]+",temp:"+data[2]/100+",hum:"+data[3]/100;
    return [[{payload: string}, {nodegroup: data[0]}]];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
```

I need the object `msg.payload` AND the `msg.nodegroup` for the `EmonCMS` node. How can I return an object containing `msg.payload` and `msg.nodegroup`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seam to returning a 2 dimensional array which will send 2 messages to the first output of the function node.

Assuming you want to send just one message to only one output then the following should do what I think you want.

```
var payload = msg.payload;
if(payload && payload.length > 10) {
   var data = payload.match(/\d+/ig);
   var string = "vcc:"+data[1]+",temp:"+data[2]/100+",hum:"+data[3]/100;
   return {payload: string, nodegroup: data[0]};
} else {
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Square bracket is missing after `data[0}` `nodegroup: data[0]};`